# How can I zoom/magnify Cinnamon desktop using the mouse wheel?

Tags: desktop, mouse, cinnamon

There is a wonderful feature of compiz that allows me to use a key+mouse wheel (I use <kbd>win</kbd>+wheel to zoom into the desktop. Is there a way to get the same effect in Cinnamon?

UPDATE: Following Mikko Rantalainen's solution below, I checked gnome-shell-mousewheel-zoom out from git and added the included executable to my start up programs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See source at https://github.com/tobiasquinn/gnome-shell-mousewheel-zoom

Install for Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tobias-quinn/gsmz
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-mousewheel-zoom
mousewheelzoom &
```

Done. Zoom with Alt+Mousewheel.

**Update 2015-03-17:**

Since around Cinnamon 2.2 API has changed so much that the Gnome Shell Mouse Wheel Zoom application no longer works with Cinnamon. However, Cinnamon has integrated zoom as an accessibility feature. All you need to do is to open Cinnamon Preferences and select `Accessibility` and toggle `Zoom` to `ON`. After that `Super`+`Mouse wheel up/down` zooms the desktop. You can even adjust the scrolling behavior in `Options...` – I recommend using full screen for the zoom and selecting `Magnifier cursor pushes contents around`.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to get this working on a debian (not Ubuntu, so no ppas) system?

Comment: I guess you have to compile the software from the source. Something like this should work: `git clone git://github.com/tobiasquinn/gnome-shell-mousewheel-zoom.git; cd gnome-shell-mousewheel-zoom; debuild`. See the messages and install missing build dependencies to get it to build. When you're done .deb packages should appear one directory above your current directory.

Comment: I had actually tried this before but `make` failed with various cryptic errors. I had not noticed that there was already a compiled executable in the git bundle and that one works fine with debian. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is currently not working for Ubuntu 13.04 :(

Comment: as the update states just set it up in your accessibility settings, no need to download anything else.  works in Linux Mint 18.3